# java Lock using MAP causing a deadlock

Tags: java, hashmap, locking

I have written code where 3 threads are involved:-
1. Thread1 -> decrements the Map created in the main thread
2. Thread2 -> responsible for checking the size of the map, once it is 0, exit
3. Thread3 -> starts to work once the size is 0, waits till the size is 0.

Thread1 is easy to implement, for Thread2 and Thread3 I am using reentrantLock.
The problem is, Thread2 is not breaking once the size of the map reaches 0 and therefore Thread3 is blocked forever.
Not sure, what the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

    public class MainClass {

    static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        map.put("key1", "valu1");
        map.put("key2", "valu1");
        map.put("key3", "valu1");
        map.put("key4", "valu1");
        map.put("key5", "valu1");
        map.put("key6", "valu1");
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        decrementThread(lock);
        Thread3(lock);
        Thread2(lock);
    }

    static void decrementThread(Lock lock) {
        System.out.println("starting decrement thread");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Integer i = 0;
                    while(i<6) {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    String key = "key" + ((++i).toString());
                    System.out.println(key);
                    map.remove(key);
                    System.out.println("removed" + map.size());
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    static void Thread3(final Lock lock) {
        System.out.println("starting Thread3");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println("got for the lock");
                while(true) {
                    //System.out.println(map.size());
                    if(map.size() == 0) {
                        System.out.println("breaking");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("unlocking");
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    static void Thread2(final Lock lock) {
        System.out.println("starting mail thread");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {         
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("waiting for the lock");
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println("Thread2 locked");
                lock.unlock();

            }
        }).start();
        }

    }
```

Thanks,
Amar

Comment: I'd wonder why you would do this complicated thing when ConcurrentHashMap would handle it for you.

Comment: @duffymo the problem is that my thread that checks for the mapsize does not release the lock.

Comment: so I replaced HasMap with ConcurrentHashMap and the exact code above worked. Now I am wondering why the Thread is able to come out of the Lock when using ConcurrentHashMap and not when using HashMap ??

Comment: Writing multi-threaded code properly is hard.  I'm thinking that you are working at too low a level and not doing it correctly.  Better to use the newer constructs in the java.util.concurrent package than Thread.